# animation doesn't fire on every click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Clearly, the intention of this animation is to turn all "editable" elements to a blue color in 300 ms, and then slowly fade back to the body background color over the course of 1000 ms. Basically, make them "blink".

```
$('#highlight_button').click( function (e) {
    var x = $('body').css('background-color');
    $('.editable').animate({backgroundColor: '#0000ff'}, 300, function() {
                    $('.editable').animate({backgroundColor: x}, 1000); 
    });
});
```

When the page loads, it always seems to work as intended on the first click. However, with subsequent clicks it fires only periodically, or with a very long delay. I suppose a solution would involve not queuing this animation, but looking around it isn't clear to me how to do this. Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding some stops to your animation, like so:

```
$('#highlight_button').click( function (e) {
    var x = $('body').css('background-color');
    $('.editable').stop(true, true).animate({backgroundColor: '#0000ff'}, 300, function() {
                    $('.editable').stop(true, true).animate({backgroundColor: x}, 1000); 
    });
});
```

Also, just chaining the second animation would probably do the same as putting it in the callback.

```
$('#highlight_button').click( function (e) {
    $('.editable').stop(true, true).animate({backgroundColor: '#0000ff'}, 300).animate({backgroundColor: $('body').css('background-color')}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Hm.. when I do that it seems to turn the bgcolor blue, and not animate to return the the normal bgcolor

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it. Seemed to fix my problem. Have a good day

Comment: This solution will make overhead and also remove all other animation that element had before(may be in another function or script)

Comment: How would stop() add overhead when clearQeue is set to true. It does exactly what your answer does and then some, in a much easier way! The only thing I agree on is that it will stop other animations running on the same element, but it will not remove them. This is usually not a problem for most applications, and stop() is recommended for most animations to prevent looping anyway.

Comment: Because you call +1 function, and will use animation stack.And it will be removed from stack because you played already.

Answer (score 1):

When you use jQuery.animate, each new aniamtion added to animation stack from wich then played. If you don't need such behavior just add `queue` param to the animation params, this make each new animation stop previous. Like so:

```
$('.editable').animate({backgroundColor: x}, {duration:1000, queue:false});
```